# Make a ToolStrip Button staying highlighted when clicked in C#

Tags: c#, winforms, toolstrip

I have a simple ToolStrip with buttons in it which contain images and text. When I go over that button it changes appearance (same when it gets clicked). How can I customize this so that it stays highlighted when clicked? I have to do this over a tabControl so that it stays highlighted when the tab is entered and gets back to its normal appearance when leaving the tab. Which methods do I have to override?

Thank you!

Comment: I'm not sure if that's the appearance you want, but try setting the `Checked` property of the button to `true` when the tab has been entered and to `false` when it's been left.

Comment: And for the methods: `TabControl` and`TabPage` both have events `Enter` and `Leave` which you can use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just set `ToolStripButton.CheckOnClick` property to `true` from design time. So it will stay highlited when clicked.

About the other requirement set `ToolStripButton.Checked` to `true` on entring the tab control, and set it to `false` on leaving the tab control.

For entering and leaving you may use `Control.Leave` & `Control.Enter` events of tabpage/tabcontrol.

Let me know incase of any issues

Comment: Thank you! Did not know that this can be so easy

Comment: @Jackson30, I'm happy it served your purpose.